# Select specific radio item in foreach

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, foreach

I have some data witch i looping in foreach. That data is `input type=radio` buttons with name. How can i select specific item in foreach.

**My code:**

```
<?php foreach($items as $item): ?>
   <input type="radio" name="price" value="<?= $item['id'];?>"> <?= $item['name'];?> // 15 items looped
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Output**

```
<input type="radio" name="price" value="1"> 10$
<input type="radio" name="price" value="2"> 20$
<input type="radio" name="price" value="3"> 30$
<input type="radio" name="price" value="4"> 40$
<input type="radio" name="price" value="5"> 50$
<input type="radio" name="price" value="6"> 60$
```

I have custom price buttons. When i click on on button i want to select one specific radio button in `foreach`.

```
<button>select 10$ </button>
<button>select 20$ </button>
<button>select 30$ </button>
```

Comment: _"I have custom price buttons. When i click on on button i want to select one specific radio button in foreach."_ ? `foreach` at `php` is completed when `button` element is clicked ? What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I do not understand what is unclear... When i click on button i want to select specific radio button in `foreach`. button does not depend on foreach. Just want to trigger event

Comment: Why would the user click a button, and not just click the radio?

Comment: That is not possible. The `foreach` loop at `php` should be completed by the time the `button` at rendered `html` document is clicked. When `button` is clicked what should occur ?

Comment: The problem is more complicated in the application. This is just an example that I need to use in the application.

Comment: Is requirement to select `input` element that has same text after it as `button` element has as `html` within it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `data-*` attribute to both `input` , `button` elements that are the same, use `.filter()` to select elements that have the same `.data()` value at `click` of `button`, `.prop("checked", true)` to select the `input` element matching `button` element `.data()`

```js
$("button").click(function(e) {
  $("input").filter(function(i, el) {
    return $(el).data("value") === $(e.target).data("value")
  }).prop("checked", true)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="radio" name="price" value="1" data-value="$10"> 10$
<input type="radio" name="price" value="2" data-value="$20"> 20$
<input type="radio" name="price" value="3" data-value="$30"> 30$
<input type="radio" name="price" value="4" data-value="40"> 40$
<input type="radio" name="price" value="5" data-value="$50"> 50$
<input type="radio" name="price" value="6" data-value="60"> 60$
<button data-value="$10">select 10$ </button>
<button data-value="$20">select 20$ </button>
<button data-value="$30">select 30$ </button>
```

Comment: To do this , you must load external jquery. It is overkill to load complete extra library to do this small task. Question does not mentions use of jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Check out below piece of code.

```
<?php foreach($items as $item): ?>
   `<label><input type="radio" name="price" value="<?= $item['price'];?>"> <?= $item['name'];?></label>` // 15 items looped
<?php endif; ?>
```

Importantly wrap your radio buttons within label tag, because interactively this is more user friendly, as the user feels easier to click the radio buttons text instead of radio button directly.

Jquery for selecting respective button.

```
$("button").click(function() {
   var getSelectedText = $(this).text().split(" ");
  $("input[type=radio][name=price]").filter(function() { return ($(this).parent().text().trim().toLowerCase()==getSelectedText[1].trim().toLowerCase()); }).attr("checked", true);
});
```

here we go with you required solution.. :)

**Terms Used**

`.split()` expects one parameter `'with what string to split'`, here in your case it is `'space'`

`.filter()` a callback function, this returns the callback return with limited number of results, as per requirement, in your case matching the radio buttons text.

https://jsfiddle.net/zcvt1jo4/

Comment: The OP wants to select the input when the button is clicked, I think this does the opposite.

Comment: hey @AdamKonieska, is this fine now? :)

Answer (score 1):

If your html looks like this:

```
<div id="checkboxes">
    <input type="radio" name="price" value="1"> 10$
    <input type="radio" name="price" value="2"> 20$
    <input type="radio" name="price" value="3"> 30$
    <input type="radio" name="price" value="4"> 40$
    <input type="radio" name="price" value="5"> 50$
    <input type="radio" name="price" value="6"> 60$
</div>

<div id="buttons">
    <button data-val="1">select 10$ </button>
    <button data-val="2">select 20$ </button>
    <button data-val="3">select 30$ </button>
    <button data-val="4">select 40$ </button>
    <button data-val="5">select 50$ </button>
    <button data-val="6">select 60$ </button>
</div>
```

This jQuery javascript should work:

```
$('#buttons button').click(function() {
  var value = $(this).data('val');
  $('#checkboxes input').eq(value-1).attr('checked', true);
})
```

Put it all together in a jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/t1z1pm8x/

Comment: Close, but `$('#buttons button')` is not going to find any matches.

Comment: @AdamKonieska I noticed that when I was jsfiddling it, but then I didn't fix it in my answer. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

For doing this simple task , use of jQuery is overkill . 
this can be achived using only javascript.

```
<?php 
$i = 0
foreach($items as $item){ 
?>
<input type="radio" name="price" id="i<?=$i?>" value="<?= $item['price'];?>"><?= $item['name'];?> // 15 items looped
<?  $i++;   } ?>
```

Output:

```
<input type="radio" name="price" id="i1" value="1"> 10$
<input type="radio" name="price" id="i2" value="2"> 20$
<input type="radio" name="price" id="i3" value="3"> 30$
<input type="radio" name="price" id="i4" value="4"> 40$
<input type="radio" name="price" id="i5" value="5"> 50$
<input type="radio" name="price" id="i6" value="6"> 60$

<button id="1" onclick="select_radio(this.id)">select 10$ </button>
<button id="2" onclick="select_radio(this.id)">select 20$ </button>
<button id="3" onclick="select_radio(this.id)">select 30$ </button>
```

define a function

```
function select_radio(id){
    document.getElementById("i"+id).checked = true;
}
```